# delete.retention.ms at the time of creating topic in kafka on 0.8.1 version

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, kafka-consumer-api

I have configured this property delete.retention.ms at the time of creating topic in kafka on 0.8.1 version.What this property does ? Will this delete message after the specific time interval from kafka.

Answer (score 8):

No, `delete.retention.ms` or `log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms` is a property used in [log compaction](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#compaction) which is turned off as a default.
`log.rentention.hours` is a property that you can control when messages are deleted.

From [Broker Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) of Kafka 0.8.1 documentation

**log.retention.hours**

> The amount of time to keep a log segment before it is deleted, i.e. the default data retention window for all topics. Note that if both log.retention.minutes and log.retention.bytes are both set we delete a segment when either limit is exceeded.

**log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms**

> The amount of time to retain delete tombstone markers for log compacted topics. This setting also gives a bound on the time in which a consumer must complete a read if they begin from offset 0 to ensure that they get a valid snapshot of the final stage (otherwise delete tombstones may be collected before they complete their scan).

Comment: in which scenario should i use "log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms" . suppose if i set the retention time to be 6 sec at the time of topic creation then what will happen with the message.COuld you please help me to get through this.

Comment: `log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms` determines how often the log compaction occurs. If you set the value of the parameter to be 6 seconds, the log compaction will occur every 6 seconds. The log compaction involves some overhead, so I guess it is not intended to work like that often.

Comment: Log compaction: Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition. It addresses use cases and scenarios such as restoring state after application crashes or system failure, or reloading caches after application restarts during operational maintenance. (http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#compaction)

Comment: So it shrinks partitions so that the only up-to-date value is remaining within the same message key. http://kafka.apache.org/images/log_compaction.png

Comment: KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> keyedMessage = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>(request.getRequestTopicName(),SerializationUtils.serialize(message)); producer.send(keyedMessage);  
 Currently,I am sending message without any key maintained as part of keyed message , will it still work with delete.retention.ms ,Do i need to send key as part of message? Is this good to make key as part of message.